# Getting separate arrays instead of one using for loop and push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```js
let date = new Date()
let tomorrowdate = date.getDate() + 1


for (let i = 0; i < data.list.map((data) => data.dt_txt).length; i++) {
  let actualdate = new Date(data.list.map((data) => data.dt_txt)[i]).getDate()
  if (actualdate == tomorrowdate) {
    const maxtemp = []
                                    
    Math.max(maxtemp.push(data.list[i].main.temp))
```

I'm trying to find tomorrow's max temperature from an API but the results I'm getting are separate arrays of the temperatures instead of just one array with all the temperatures.

Comment: Hi, can you share the arrays please ?

Comment: if you'r array looks something like this (nested) [[temp1], [temp2], ...] you can use the .flat() method on the array - but without seeing the arrays/output, we can only guess to what your issue is, so please share them

Comment: Not sure I'm doing it right. The array is in an object. This is just part of it, index 0 of an array of 40.

Object
city: {id: 3054456, name: 'Csabrendek', coord: {…}, country: 'HU', population: 2948, …}
list: Array(40)
0:
clouds: {all: 80}
dt: 1658869200
dt_txt: "2022-07-26 21:00:00"
main: {temp: 293.45, feels_like: 293.26, temp_min: 292.43, temp_max: 293.45, pressure: 1013, …}

Output (These are the first 2 I get from the 8 which is fine because they are all from tomorrow. 
Array(1)
0: 291.99
length: 1
Array(1)
0: 289.67
length: 1